# Mouseout on a set of divs not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseout

I was implementing a code in which i have parent div which contains n number of child divs. I have a mouseout function for main div as well as different mouseout function for child divs.

My code structure will be like this.

```
<div id="root" onmouseout="dohide('main');">
<div id="top">title</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="1" onmouseover="changecolor(this.id);" onmouseout="recolor(this.id);">1</div>
<div id="2" onmouseover="changecolor(this.id);" onmouseout="recolor(this.id);">2</div>
<div id="3" onmouseover="changecolor(this.id);" onmouseout="recolor(this.id);">3</div>
<div id="4" onmouseover="changecolor(this.id);" onmouseout="recolor(this.id);">4</div>
<div id="5" onmouseover="changecolor(this.id);" onmouseout="recolor(this.id);">5</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The code works weird when i mousein. When i mouseover the main div it visibility is set to hidden. But my code was to change the visibility only when mouseout. Is it because of the child divs inside the parent div? How to rectify it?

```
function dohide(cb_hd_id)
{
if(document.getElementById(cb_hd_id).style.visibility=="visible")
{
document.getElementById(cb_hd_id).style.visibility="hidden";
}
else
{
}
}
```

Comment: Comment if you're going to down-vote people!

Comment: Can you provide the changecolour(), dohide() and recolor() methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `div#root` is just a wrapper div, it doesn't have any directly visual text node or padding white space. So it won't issue an mouse event on its own.

It receives the `mouseout` event from its visible descendent elements, by [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). So any time your mouse leaves `div#top` or `div#main` (`div#1`, `div#2`, ... indeed), an `mouseout` event will be raised and bubbled to `div#root`.

Since you didn't explain the detailed effects you want, no good answer can be made.

If you are writing a dropdown navigation panel with `mouseover`/`mouseout` effects, you can add an `mouseover` handler to `div#root` to show `div#main`. When you move your mouse from one item to another in `div#main`, `mouseover` will fired after `mouseout` and before the execution of the `mouseout` handler.

Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/eq32B/) to see if it's what you want. Note that the hover effect can be implemented [purely in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/CbHnF/).

Comment: You saved me quite the headache letting us know about the ability to do it in CSS. I wish I had more than one upvote.